# How to Get Groups of Files from GetFiles()

Tags: c#

I have to process files everyday.  The files are named like so:

```
 fg1a.mmddyyyy
 fg1b.mmddyyyy
 fg1c.mmddyyyy

 fg2a.mmddyyyy
 fg2b.mmddyyyy
 fg2c.mmddyyyy
 fg2d.mmddyyyy
```

If the entire file group is there for a particular date, I can process it.  If it isn't there, I should not process it.  I may have several partial file groups that run over several days.  So when I have fg1a.12062017, fg1b.12062017 and fg1c.12062017, I can process that group (fg1) only.

Here is my code so far.  It doesn't work because I can't figure out how to get only the full groups to add to the the processing file list.

```
        fileList = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp\");

        string[] fileGroup1 = { "FG1A", "FG1B", "FG1C" }; // THIS IS A FULL GROUP
        string[] fileGroup2 = { "FG2A", "FG2B", "FG2C", "FG2D" };

        List<string> fileDates = new List<string>();
        List<string> procFileList;

        // get a list of file dates
        foreach (string fn in fileList)
        {
            string dateString = fn.Substring(fn.IndexOf('.'), 9);
            if (!fileDates.Contains(dateString))
            {
                fileDates.Add(dateString);
            }
        }

        bool allFiles = true;
        foreach (string fg in fileGroup1)
        {
            foreach (string fd in fileDates)
            {
                string finder = fg + fd;
                bool foundIt = false;
                foreach (string fn in fileList)
                {
                    if (fn.ToUpper().Contains(finder))
                    {
                        foundIt = true;
                    }

                }
                if (!foundIt)
                {
                    allFiles = false;
                }

                else
                {    
                    foreach (string fn in fileList)
                    {
                        procFileList.Add(fn);
                    }

                }

            }

        }

        foreach (string fg in fileGroup2)
        {
            foreach (string fd in fileDates)
            {
                string finder = fg + fd;
                bool foundIt = false;
                foreach (string fn in fileList)
                {
                    if (fn.ToUpper().Contains(finder))
                    {
                        foundIt = true;
                    }

                }
                if (!foundIt)
                {
                    allFiles = false;
                }
                else
                {    
                    foreach (string fn in fileList)
                    {
                        procFileList.Add(fn);
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't seem to have told us how to determine if a group is full or not? Is it 7 items, ignore the date? Is the date relevant? Do group 1 and group 2 operate independently of each other? If group 2 has 4 items with a different date to three items in group 1 are we full?

Comment: @CaiusJard The group is full when all the files of the group are there so for fg1 it would be fg1a, fg1b and fg1c all of the same date.    We must have a complete set for a particular date.  Each group operates independently of another.

Comment: What about the date? What if I have two fg1a from Monday and Tuesday, fg1b from weds and another 2 fg1c on thurs? Which ones go with which?

Comment: The file name  has the date in it -- so I need fg1a.12062017, fg1b.12062017 and fg1c.12062017 to process file group 1

Comment: How long may a group languish incomplete for on disk? What mechanism do you have for signalling that a filegroup is processed? Does the fact that fg1x.11062017 is incomplete inhibit you from processing 12062017? In what order shall two complete file groups be processed?

Comment: When the file group is processed, it is moved to another directory.  An incomplete fg1x.11062017 does not inhibit you from processing 12062017.  It's mere presence or absence is an indicator of whether it still needs to be processed.

Comment: Last question, maybe- is the process that creates the files reliable at naming them, or might it one day make an fg1b fg1c fg1d and this group must not be processed because, though it contains three fg1x files, they are not fg1a/b/c

Comment: Yes - 100% reliable.  Thank you for thinking about this :)  @CaiusJard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it can sometimes get messy dealing with multiple lists, groupings, and parsing file names, I would start by creating a class that represents a `FileGroupItem`. This class would have a `Parse` method that takes in a file path, and then has properties that represent the group part and date part of the file name, as well as the full path to the file:

```
public class FileGroupItem
{
    public string DatePart { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    public static FileGroupItem Parse(string filePath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath)) return null;

        // Split the file name on the '.' character to get the group and date parts
        var fileParts = Path.GetFileName(filePath).Split('.');
        if (fileParts.Length != 2) return null;

        return new FileGroupItem
        {
            GroupName = fileParts[0],
            DatePart = fileParts[1],
            FilePath = filePath
        };
    }            
}
```

Then, in my main code, I would create a list of the file group definitions, and then populate a list of `FileGroupItems` from the directory we're scanning. After that, we can determine if any file group definition is complete by comparing it's items (in a case-insensitive way) to the actual `FileGroupItems` we found in the directory (after first grouping the `FileGroupItems` by it's `DatePart`). If the intersection of these two lists has the same number of items as the file group definition, then it's complete and we can process that group.

Maybe it will make more sense in code:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var scanDirectory = @"f:\public\temp\";
    var processedDirectory = @"f:\public\temp2\";

    // The lists that define a complete group
    var fileGroupDefinitions = new List<List<string>>
    {
        new List<string> {"FG1A", "FG1B", "FG1C"},
        new List<string> {"FG2A", "FG2B", "FG2C", "FG2D"}
    };

    // Populate a list of FileGroupItems from the files 
    // in our directory, and group them on the DatePart
    var fileGroups = Directory.EnumerateFiles(scanDirectory)
        .Select(FileGroupItem.Parse)
        .GroupBy(f => f.DatePart);

    // Now go through each group and compare the items 
    // for that date with our file group definitions
    foreach (var fileGroup in fileGroups)
    {
        foreach (var fileGroupDefinition in fileGroupDefinitions)
        {
            // Get the intersection of the group definition and this file group
            var intersection = fileGroup
                .Where(f => fileGroupDefinition.Contains(
                    f.GroupName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                .ToList();

            // If all the items in the definition are there, then process the files
            if (intersection.Count == fileGroupDefinition.Count)
            {
                foreach (var fileGroupItem in intersection)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Processing file: {fileGroupItem.FilePath}");

                    // Move the file to the processed directory
                    File.Move(fileGroupItem.FilePath,
                        Path.Combine(processedDirectory,
                            Path.GetFileName(fileGroupItem.FilePath)));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Great solution!

Comment: Great, I hope it helps! It should work "as-is" if you update the scan and processed directory locations to your actual paths (and make any necessary updates to the file group definitions)

Comment: You are very smart.  My boss would think I gained 100 IQ points overnight if he saw that code :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could simplify your algorithm so you just have file groups as a prefix and a number of files to expect, fg1 is 3 files for a given date

I think your code to find the distinct dates present is a good idea, though you should use a hash set rather than a list, if you occasionally expect a large number of dates.. ("Valentine's Day?" - Ed)

Then you just need to work on the other loop that does the checking. An algorithm like this

```
//make a new Dictionary<string,int> for the filegroup prefixes and their counts3 
//eg myDict["fg1"] = 3; myDict["fg2"] = 4;

//list the files in the directory, into an array of fileinfo objects
//see the DirectoryInfo.GetFiles method

//foreach string d in the list of dates
 //foreach string fgKey in myDict.Keys - the list of group prefixes

 //use a bit of Linq to get all the fileinfos with a 
 //name starting with the group and ending with the date
 var grplist = myfileinfos.Where(fi => fi.Name.StartsWith(fg) && fi.Name.EndsWith(d));

 //if the grplist.Count == the filegroup count ( myDict[fgKey] )
 //then send every file in grplist for processing
 //remember that grplist is a collection of fileinfo objects,
 //if your processing method takes a string filename, use fileinfo.Fullname
```

Putting your file groupings into one dictionary will make things a lot easier than having them as x separate arrays

I haven't written all the code for you, but I've comment sketched the algorithm, and I've put in some of the more awkward bits like the link, dictionary declaration and how to fill it.. have a go at fleshing it out with code, ask any questions in a comment on this post

Comment: Thank you!  Taught me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First, create an array of the groups to make processing easier:

```
var fileGroups = new[] {
        new[] { "FG1A", "FG1B", "FG1C" },
        new[] { "FG2A", "FG2B", "FG2C", "FG2D" }
    };
```

Then you can convert the array into a `Dictionary` to map each name back to its group:

```
var fileGroupMap = fileGroups.SelectMany(g => g.Select(f => new { key = f, group = g })).ToDictionary(g => g.key, g => g.group);
```

Then, preprocess the files you get from the directory:

```
var fileList = from fname in Directory.GetFiles(...)
               select new {
                   fname,
                   fdate = Path.GetExtension(fname),
                   ffilename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fname).ToUpper()
               };
```

Now you can take your `fileList` and group by date and group, and then filter to just completed groups:

```
var profFileList = (from file in fileList
                    group file by new { file.fdate, fgroup = fileGroupMap[file.ffilename] } into fng
                    where fng.Key.fgroup.All(f => fng.Select(fn => fn.ffilename).Contains(f))
                    from fn in fng
                    select fn.fname).ToList();
```

Since you didn't preserve the groups, I flattened the groups at the end of the query into just a list of files to be processed. If you needed, you could keep them in groups and process the groups instead.

**Note:** If a file exists that belongs to no group, you will get an error from the lookup in `fileGroupMap`. If that is a possiblity you can filter the `fileList` to just known names as follows:

```
var fileList = from fname in GetFiles
               let ffilename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fname).ToUpper()
               where fileGroupMap.Keys.Contains(ffilename)
               select new {
                   fname,
                   fdate = Path.GetExtension(fname),
                   ffilename
               };
```

Also note that having a name in multiple groups will cause an error in the creation of `fileGroupMap`. If that is a possibility, the queries would become more complex and have to be written differently.

Comment: Thank you!  Very clever!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] filenames = { "fg1a.12012017", "fg1b.12012017", "fg1c.12012017", "fg2a.12012017", "fg2b.12012017", "fg2c.12012017", "fg2d.12012017" };
            new SplitFileName(filenames);
            List<List<SplitFileName>> results = SplitFileName.GetGroups(); 
        }
    }
    public class SplitFileName
    {
        public static List<SplitFileName> names = new List<SplitFileName>(); 
        string filename { get; set; }
        string prefix { get; set; }
        string letter { get; set; }
        DateTime date { get; set; }


        public SplitFileName() { }
        public SplitFileName(string[] splitNames)
        {
            foreach(string name in splitNames)
            {
                SplitFileName splitName = new SplitFileName();
                names.Add(splitName);
                splitName.filename = name;
                string[] splitArray = name.Split(new char[] { '.' });
                splitName.date = DateTime.ParseExact(splitArray[1],"MMddyyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                splitName.prefix = splitArray[0].Substring(0, splitArray[0].Length - 1);
                splitName.letter = splitArray[0].Substring(splitArray[0].Length - 1,1);
            }
        }
        public static List<List<SplitFileName>> GetGroups()
        {
            return names.OrderBy(x => x.letter).GroupBy(x => new { date = x.date, prefix = x.prefix })
                .Where(x => string.Join(",",x.Select(y => y.letter)) == "a,b,c,d")
                .Select(x => x.ToList())
                .ToList();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I was waiting for somebody to actually see the code and realize how I solved your real question.  Was expecting BRILLIANT.  The other solutions didn't use a WHERE.

Comment: It was already stated that the naming of the files was 100% accurate.

Comment: I don't think double-usage of `SplitFileName` is very good practice - you have created a bunch of `new List<SplitFileName>` that you aren't using for no reason. Also, I wouldn't assume 4 is the maximum number of filenames in a group, or that all groups names consist of prefixes followed by single letters.

Comment: All are needed to filter on the groups that have a,b,c, & d.  The code is very simple.  Does it make sense to have less objects and make the code more complicated?

Comment: What about the FG1 group, though, which only has a, b, & c?

Comment: My method GetGroups does not return a,b,c.   It only returns a,b,c,d.  That is why it is a BRILLIANT solution.  This solution deserves more than a score of 1.  Using the string.Join make it simple to test when you have all four files.

Comment: The Op said he only wanted to process the files when he got all 4 files which is exactly what my code does.  So the code isn't suppose process FG1.

Comment: No, that's not at all what they said. They said, *"So when I have fg1a.12062017, fg1b.12062017 and fg1c.12062017, I can process that group (fg1) only."* (notice that's three files). In the comments they also said, *"The group is full when all the files of the group are there so for fg1 it would be fg1a, fg1b and fg1c all of the same date"* and *"I need fg1a.12062017, fg1b.12062017 and fg1c.12062017 to process file group 1"*, and in code they have `string[] fileGroup1 = { "FG1A", "FG1B", "FG1C" }; // THIS IS A FULL GROUP`

Comment: I think that was a typo.  Should of been fg2.  The instructions says following : "If the entire file group is there for a particular date, I can process it. If it isn't there, I should not process it".

Comment: Yes, they did say that. And in code they have defined two different file groups, each with a different number of files. This is true even in the solution that the OP posted for themselves............................................ `string[] fileGroup1 = { "FG1A", "FG1B", "FG1C" }; // THIS IS A FULL GROUP` and  .......... `string[] fileGroup2 = { "FG2A", "FG2B", "FG2C", "FG2D" };`

Comment: The OP said brilliant so why are you disagreeing with the OP.  How do you ever conclude fileGroup1 is a full group?

Comment: Are different opinions not allowed?

Comment: Op said : I can't figure out how to get only the full groups to add to the the processing file list.

Comment: @rufus explained clearly why he didn't think your answer was a solution, and explained why it is not brilliant. He's entitled to his opinion. Not least because he justified it.

Comment: @jdweng, my friend, I don't know why it's so hard for you to see that the OP has two different definitions for two different file groups. *"How do you ever conclude fileGroup1 is a full group?"* By reading the code!! They've said multiple times that FG1 has three items. If you look at the solution that the OP posted below, you will see that they are still working with multiple file group definitions (though the sizes of each have changed). Please don't take any criticism personally, it's only meant to be constructive and illustrative.

Comment: It doesn't matter what Rufus thinks the OP wants.  It what the OP actually wants.  Who the !@#$%^ is THEY,  Why is everybody second guessing the OP?

Comment: The question, and comments, and accepted answer, all indicate that this answer does not meet the stated requirements. The only person second guessing the asker is you.

Answer (score 0):

With everyone's help, I solved it too.  This is what I'm going with because it's the most maintainable for me but the solutions were so smart!!!  Thanks everyone for your help.

```
   private void CheckFiles()
    {
        var fileGroups = new[] {
          new [] { "FG1A", "FG1B", "FG1C", "FG1D" },
          new[] { "FG2A", "FG2B", "FG2C", "FG2D", "FG2E" } };


        List<string> fileDates = new List<string>();
        List<string> pfiles = new List<string>();

        // get a list of file dates
        foreach (string fn in fileList)
        {
            string dateString = fn.Substring(fn.IndexOf('.'), 9);
            if (!fileDates.Contains(dateString))
            {
                fileDates.Add(dateString);
            }
        }

        // check if a date has all the files
        foreach (string fd in fileDates)
        {
            int fgCount = 0;
            // for each file group
            foreach (Array masterfg in fileGroups)
            {
                foreach (string fg in masterfg)
                {
                    // see if all the files are there
                    bool foundIt = false;
                    string finder = fg + fd;
                    foreach (string fn in fileList)
                    {
                        if (fn.ToUpper().Contains(finder))
                        {
                            pfiles.Add(fn);
                        }

                    }
                    fgCount++;

                }
                if (fgCount == pfiles.Count())
                {
                    foreach (string fn in pfiles)
                    {
                        procFileList.Add(fn);
                    }
                    pfiles.Clear();
                }
                else
                {
                    pfiles.Clear();
                }
            }
        }

        return;
    }
```